# Handling null values in Command.ExecuteScalar when the value is converted to a Type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, ado.net

I have a function to execute a query and return a scalar value like this:

```
        public T GetScalarValue<T>(string sql)
        {
            T t;
            try {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MY_SQL_SERVER_CONNECTION_STRING");
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                t = (T)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally{
                if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();
            }
            return t;
        }
```

When I call this function with the given SQL, I'll get the result:

```
int result = dal.GetScalarValue<int>("SELECT [schema_id] FROM SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE [name] = 'dbo'")
```

Since the query returns an int value this works fine, but when I call the same for the query which returns nothing my function will fail:

```
int result = dal.GetScalarValue<int>("SELECT [schema_id] FROM SYS.SCHEMAS WHERE [name] = 'Foooo'")
```

Since cmd.ExecuteScalar() returns no result,it will give "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception. But I want this function to return the default value for given Type (example: for int it should return 0, decimal-  0.00,for string - an empty value, for datetime - '1900-01-01', etc.).

If you find better solution for this please let me know.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public T GetScalarValue<T>(string sql)
{
    T result = default(T);

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MY_SQL_SERVER_CONNECTION_STRING"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var scalar = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (scalar != null)
            {
                result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(scalar, typeof(T));

                // or result = (T)scalar    if that works better for you.
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception maybe?
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here I'm setting `result` to be the default value of the type `T`. Next, if there is an exception then I just return `result` there and then. So, in your failing example, the value 0 will be returned.

EDIT:

A good point was raised in the comments. In the exception handler I've given you, I'm just returning the `result`. It would be better to log, or somehow make note, of the exception so that you know whether something has gone wrong. One idea would be to log the exception using, say, a logger like `NLog` or `Log4Net` - there's plenty of choice.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Evans. But still this will fail. Should I do something like this?
                object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (obj != null)
                    t = (T)obj;

Comment: Thanks @Jason, let me see if somebody has a better solution!

Comment: I've made a change to how I'm converting the result, since I recall that using `Convert.ChangeType` is a more thorough way then casting via `(T)`.

Comment: @JasonEvans `Convert.ChangeType` would allow conversions such `int` to `double`, but not `int` to `int?`. I think your earlier version was better, the latter conversions are more useful IMO. That said, blindly ignoring any and all exceptions is very bad, and makes it impossible for the caller to determine whether `default(T)` is what was actually returned, or (as an example) the database connection has been lost.

Answer (score 2):

Refactor your code a little bit to make more readable:

```
public T GetScalarValue<T>(string sql) where T : struct
{
    string connectionString = "MY_SQL_SERVER_CONNECTION_STRING";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var obj = command.ExecuteScalar();

        return (obj != null) ? (T)obj : default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition is the wrong way around in the `return` statement, and personally I don't see the use of your `where T : struct` requirement. +1 anyway, the core of your answer looks good :)